# Error in Batch file opening

Tags: matlab, cmd, abaqus

I am new to batch file creation and have a question regarding the same. I want to create my batch file in "D:\Documents" folder.
To create a batch file in Matlab, I use the below code

```
st = fopen('D:\Documents\MATLAB\user2.bat','w');
file1 = fopen('D:\Documents\MATLAB\user1.inp');
fprintf(st, '%s', 'call abq6134 job=',file1);
```

In the previous code,my batch file is created with name "user2.bat" and input file with name "user.inp"

Since i have a batch file and an input file created, i want to call my batch file in DOS.My abacus version is "6.13-4" . Can you let me know how to call my batch file in DOS as it gives error if i write the below code after going to directory where my input file is saved

```
call abq6134 job=user1.inp
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't understand your code. What data can we find in user1.inp? What data do you want to write to your batch file? And why do use sprintf on a string?

Comment: Yes..Since I am new to batch file creation and going through internet i found a function using springf for creation of a batch file. As i wasnt able to create using "springf" , i tried an alternate way to do it. The data in user1.inp is basically regarding the coordinates of the various elements. 

I just want to call my batch file from DOS using a command but I am not sure if my written code is wrong or the entered command in DOS. Please let me know incase you need furthur information

Comment: Can you put a small example of what your inp file looks like and what you want your batch file to look like? For example the first 5-10 lines.

Comment: Please find the attached sample of my input file. However since i have to run a batch file and havent done it before, I dont have any sample for batch file as I just want to enter a command in DOS which makes the batch file run in DOS. The content inside the window of batch file can also be empty as i just want to run it in DOS in order to open it.

Comment: But what do you want to do with the batch file? Should it open the inp file? If you want to run a batch file, you should at least know what is inside the batch file, so what the commands are. And what do you want to do with your inp file?

Comment: Yes the batch file has to open the input file

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152031/discussion-between-wazir-and-tina).

Comment: I cannot use the chat at the moment. But you can remove your input example. It wasn't very clear that you just wanted to open the input file using a batch file in DOS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling the batch file doesn't work for you because you don't call the batch file at all. When using `call abq6134 job=user1.inp` you call the input file. So what you need is to use `call user2.bat`. In user2.bat you need to specify what you want to open, just like you did with your code in Matlab but don't put "call" in front of the file you want to open: `fprintf(st, '%s', 'abq6134 job=',file1)`.